# Create one div with text and image separate?

Tags: css, image, html, text

I am currently coding my first website, and one of the elements I have are "story blocks" that are a fixed width and split between images and text, but all in one div. Here is an image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHIeh.jpg.

Let me explain the different parts going on here: an image with a slight black overlay as well as text on the left, and then text describing the story on the right. Currently, I have an inefficient way of creating this element, involving two separate divs and disparate headers for the story titles. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="story-image"> 
  <h2 class="story-head">STORY TITLE</h2>
  <img src="http://gearpatrol.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/microsoft-surface-gear-patrol1.jpg"/>
</div>
 <!--this ends the image and title part, begins the text part-->
<div class="story-text">
  <h5>Story description.</h5>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.story-image {
    position: inherit;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.39); 
    margin-left: 58px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100px;}
.story-head {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 800;
    width:220px;
    line-height:100px;}
.story-text {
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;}
.story-text h5 {
    padding-left:8px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle; }
```

As you can see, it isn't the most efficient way of doing this sort of thing and can cause issues where the two elements break away from eachother (example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAYu3.png). I cannot figure out a way to have one single div that is divided between image and text. Does anyone know of a possible way to do this? Thank you and happy holidays!

Comment: So you don't want an inner div containing the text to the left?

Comment: I want the title text on the left to be overlaid ontop of the image, and the description text on the right. Basically the most efficient way to code what the image shows. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.container { 
    width:400px; 
    display:inline-block; 
    height:80px; 
    margin-right:10px; 
    padding:0; 
}


.left { 
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    width:120px; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;   
    height:80px; 
    background-image:url(URL); 
    background-size:100%; 
}

.right { 
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    width:280px; 
    padding:0 10px; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">tjen<br>a</div>
    <div class="right">tjen<br>a</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/F3LxY/3/)

The problem with the two elements becoming break appart in some situations should be gone, and you can change `vertical-align:middle` to `top` or `bottom` if you want the text to have a different position in the div. Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks good! One question, if the text on the right is floating right, will I be able to center it within the text description part of the element?

Comment: @user3126301 Sorry for my late reply. Take a look at my updated answer. That issue should be resolved now.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but just one more thing: is it possible to have some sort of shadow or overlay to darken the image? Thanks again and apologies!